# SDK raspberry pi4 qt5

Tags: qt, sdk, qt5, yocto, raspberry-pi4

Someone by chance is aware of the existence of a ready-made SDK for Qt5 to cross compile the code for raspberry pi4?

Cause I'm coding with Qt on ubuntu 20.04, and I'm trying to cross compile from Qt.

Thanks

Comment: Qt has Boot2Qt that has supported rpi4. It may only be available for commercial users though.

Comment: It's up from the system on rpi. What do you use?